# Manually inserting site tagline

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to manually add a site tagline into the header image of my website. Below is the Jquery and CSS that I am using. Have not been able to get any text to show up.

www.jobspark.ca

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#banner-area").prepend("<div id='banner-tagline'>Tagline</div>");
});
</script>


#banner-tagline { color: #fff; font-size: 40px; text-align:center;  z-index: 99999; }
```

[image]

UPDATE
Awesome thanks that did the trick. Only issue left is that is show up in front of my fixed navigation when scrolling down and I would like it more centred vertically on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just update your "banner-tagline" css as follows. I have just added top position. Hope it will work for you.

```
#banner-tagline {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 99999;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `position: absolute` to your #banner-tagline element CSS.
EDITED: Additionally, `z-index` only takes effect if with an `absolute` or `fixed` position.

Answer (score 1):

z-index only works on positioned elements, so add position:relative (or position:absolute depending on how you will position your tagline) to the style for #banner-tagline.